# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL

Tags: android, retrofit

Retrofit Builder:

```
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit=builder.build();
    UserClient userClient=retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
```

The Problem:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.saiid.authetification/com.example.saiid.authetification.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL:
```

Answer (score 1):

Base url should be something like this :

```
public final String BASE_URL = "http://18.156.18.81:8080";
```

So it will start from http:// or https:// use it as :

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way ..http://

```
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://recrutement.stb.com.tn:1010/PlateformeApi_Externe/api/Authorize/").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
    UserClient userClient = retrofit.create(UserClient.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing protocol in your Base URL. Your Base URL must start with `http://` or `https://`.